# Why are there extra null elements in my list?

Tags: java, arraylist

When I read from standard input, only alternate positions in the `ArrayList` are taking up data. The input data is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
```

I have tried this on multiple places but I am still getting the same output.

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> strings= new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            strings.add(null);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            strings.add(9-i, br.readLine());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(strings.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

The result I expect:

```
0
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

The actual result:

```
0
null
9
null
8
null
7
null
6
null
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with this? for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        strings.add(null);
    }

Comment: From the javadoc of  `add(int index,
       E element)` :  "Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices)." : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-

Comment: Stultuske sir, thats because add(index, element) does not work if the list at the index has nothing initially. I had too fill it with something to use the add method. Thanks.

Comment: Arnaud Sir, Even if the method shifts stuff to the right it should still insert the values i am giving at the positions i want? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5):

The `add` in `strings.add(9-i, br.readLine())` performs an insertion, not a replacement. The previous loop as the `nulls` you are seeing.

To get the desired result, simply insert into the first position, after getting rid of the first loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    strings.add(0, br.readLine());
}
```

If you were trying to pre-allocate the list to avoid shifting, use `set` instead of `add` to replace the values:

```
for(int i = strings.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    strings.set(i, br.readLine());
}
```

There's no reason to compute `9 - i` at each iteration.

Comment: Sir i wish to insert the elements from the last position. I have added null elements in order to use the add() method, i had to add something :p. add() method inserts the elements at the specific position, so why is it skipping positions?

Comment: @Prateek.  Add inserts. That means all the indices shift when you do that. If you want nulls in the final result, make that clear in the question. Perhaps print the whole list instead of just the first 10 elements. You can use`List.size()` instead of hard coding the loop size.

Answer (score 3):

You should change

```
strings.add(9-i, br.readLine());
```

to

```
strings.set(9-i, br.readLine());
```

This will replace the `null` values with the inputs instead of inserting the input between the `null` elements of the `List`.

Comment: Thanks it works! But why was the add() methid not working?

Comment: @PrateekMishra `add` was working, but it added the elements in addition to the existing nulls, so you got a list that contains `0, null, 9, null, ..., 1, null`. And you only printed half of it in your last loop.

Comment: But shouldn't it add elements to the positions i have specified?

Comment: @PrateekMishra It did. add(9,1) put 1 in index 9, pushing the null that was there to index 10, and resulting in null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,1,null. Then add(8,2) put 2 in index 8, pushing the elements following it, and resulting in null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,2,null,1,null, and so on...

Comment: Thankyou. I get it now!

Answer (score 0):

First remove and than add, like this:

```
public static void main( String args[] ) throws IOException {

            ArrayList<String> strings= new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                strings.add(br.toString());
            }
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                strings.remove(9-i);
                strings.add(9-i, br.readLine());
            }
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                System.out.println(strings.get(i));

}
```